# Delete folder in user's Temp directory but also take unicode foldernames into account

Tags: c++, windows, file, winapi, unicode

I am trying to delete a folder in the user's Temp directory %localappdata%/Temp to cleanup some remnant empty folders however I am not sure how to do it and also need to take unicode paths into account.

I was using,

```
double delete_tempfolder(const char* directory_name) {
    rmdir(directory_name);
    return 1;
}

int main(){

    delete_tempfolder("C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\TMPDIR");
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

but as soon as the directory used non-ASCII characters, rmdir stopped working, I'll need it able to be working with unicode characters as Username folders in that path usually have them.

Comment: What compiler are you using? A `char` array can't hold wide strings. In Visual Studio you could use [_wrmdir](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt8es881.aspx)

Comment: I am using MinGW g++ with -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -D UNICODE -D _UNICODE -O3 -DNDEBUG -s -o "_Test.exe"

Comment: MinGW should still have access to `_wrmdir()`. If not, use MinGW-w64. Be sure to prefix your string literals with `L` (so `L"C:\\whatever.txt"`) and use `wchar_t *` instead of `char *`.

Comment: This hasn't anything to do with deleting directories really. This issue is how text is represented in UTF-16 in Windows. That's what you need to research. Getting us to teach you that isn't productive.

Comment: I finally did it, will update with my answer

Answer (score -2):

Read a bit more on MultiByteToWideChar(), this worked for me, it was able to remove also directories with non-ASCII names.

```
double fn_directory_remove(const char* lpath) {

    int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8 , 0 , lpath, -1, NULL, 0);

    WCHAR* wstr = new WCHAR[wchars_num];

    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, lpath, -1, wstr, wchars_num);

    // print directory to delete
    std::wcout << wstr;

    if (RemoveDirectoryW(wstr)) {
        delete[] wstr;
        return 1;
    } else {
        delete[] wstr;
        return 0;
    }

}


// note: should use GetTempPathW() to get actual user Temp directory
double _out = fn_directory_remove("C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\TEMPDIR");
cout << "Deleted directory (%localappdata%\\Temp\\TEMPDIR\\): " << _out << endl;
```

Comment: Windows does not support UTF-8 encoded paths.  Use `CP_ACP` instead of `CP_UTF8`.  Or, just don't use `char*` to begin with, use `wchar_t*` instead, then you don't need to use `MultiByteToWideChar()`.

Comment: Massive overcomplication. Stop using ANSI and use the native encoding UTF-16

Comment: I should have said that I need to call the function in a DLL. I can only pass the lpath string as LPCSTR (due to framework either supporting LPCSTR or double), so I'd need to use MultiByteToWideChar(), no?

Comment: If the signature for a function wants a pointer, you can pass in any pointer. You merely need to cast it on either side of the call from/to the appropriate type. I don't understand, how a DLL changes anything.